# Communication between Erlang and c program

Tags: erlang, port

When erlang module communicates with a c program via a port it sends a packet to the c program my question is when i create a port using this configuration

```
Port = open_port({spawn, ExtPrg}, [{packet, 2}]).
```

- what are the parameters sent in the packet ?
- what is the length of each parameter?

Comment: This question isn't clear. Are you saying that just the act of calling `open_port` in this fashion is causing data to be sent to the external program? Or are you asking what `{packet,2}` does? Did you read [the documentation for that packet option](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/erlang.html#open_port-2)?

Comment: i want know what are the parameter sent by the erlang module to c this will help me to implement the function in c that decode the packet

Comment: Again, please clarify what is "parameter" in your meaning. If you ask for command line parameters, they are exactly as specified in ExtPrg. After they are sent, the C program shall wait for byte stream on stdin, in which each message is prepended with 2-byte length in big-engian order. Responses are to be sent to C program stdout in the same manner. Is this explanation enough?

Comment: Thank you,This the solution of my problem would you please answer the question or i do it my self ?,Is there a way to see the data flow between erlang and the c program?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Erlang module and C program communicate via stdin and stdout by sending byte stream(sequence of bytes).

Creating a port with

```
Port = open_port({spawn, ExtPrg}, [{packet, N}]).
```

(valid values for N are 1,2,4)

tells erlang that the packets sent will be in this format :

- N bytes : data length of the packet (we can conclude the data length)
- data length bytes : data